# Записать в JSON с помощью node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, nw.js

привет есть json такова вида

```
[{
    "vanila": {
        "example1": "127.0.0.1",
        "example2": "127.0.0.1",
        "example3": "127.0.0.1",
        "example4": "127.0.0.1"
    },
    "crusade":{
        "example1": "127.0.0.1",
        "example2": "127.0.0.1",
        "example3": "127.0.0.1",
        "example4": "127.0.0.1"
    }
}]
```

мне надо в раздел crusade добавить еще строку.
Как сделать подскажите.
приложение создается с помощью nw.js и json лежит локально в соседней папки.
Я знаю что надо использовать модуль fs

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

как бы думаю 
сделать так

```
var json = require('app/js/client.json');
```

и потом как в массив пушить но как именно в конкретный раздел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не тестил, писал прямо тут, но прмиерно так. Хотя этот способ будет медленно работать при оочень больших файлах.

```js
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('app/js/client.json', (err, buffer) => {
    let data = JSON.parse(buffer.toString());
    data[0]['crusade']['newKey'] = 'newvalue';
    fs.writeFileSync('app/js/client.json', data);
})
```

Comment: 1. `buffer.toString()` - ну сколько ж можно. Укажи сразу ему кодировку и он вместо буфера отдаст в коллбэк строку. 2. Из каких соображений чтение асинхронное, а запись синхронная?

Comment: Я изменил json и сделал вот так $('.btn-add').click(function(){
  $.getJSON('/app/js/client.json', function(data){
   var array = data;
   array.classic.push({"name": "alex", "realm": "russia"});
   $.each(array.classic, function(key, val){
    alert(val.name + "  " + val.realm)
   });
  });
});